# Timed Jquery events using .each

Tags: jquery, settimeout, each

I am trying to simulate a click event on list items with the same class, one at a time every few seconds. I have tried this many different ways. Using combinations of .each and delay() result in all clicks being triggered at the same time. I found someone with a similar question and the answer was to do the following...

```
            var elements = $(this).find('.slide');
            var index = 0;

            setTimeout(function () {
                $(elements).get(index).trigger("click");
                index++;
            }, 3000);
```

This gives me a js error every time and doesn't seem to fill the array...maybe I'm missing something obvious...

Thanks

Comment: We need your html here, do you have elements with the class '.slide'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`jQuery.fn.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only works for animations made with jQuery, there is no way of delaying code using the jQuery core as of yet. There, however, are [plugins implementing `setTimeout()`](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/settimeout) and the likes into jQuery, but they don't add much functionality over the original [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

As for fixing your code ;) 
[`jQuery.fn.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) gets the actual HTMLDomElement, and it has no method `.click()`. (I expect that is the error you are getting.)
Use [`jQuery.fn.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead. Also, use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`, to make it work multiple times and then when all are "clicked", clear the interval:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  elements.eq(index).trigger("click");
  index++;
  if(index == elements.size()){
    clearTimeout(interval);
  }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is completely out of context code how I would trigger a click on .list-elements every 1 second using recursive timeout

```
 (function(){
var listElements = jQuery( ".list-elements" ), i = 0;

     function triggerClick(){

        if( listElements[i] ) {
        listElements.eq( i++ ).trigger( "click" );
        window.setTimeout( triggerClick, 1000 );
        }

     }
window.setTimeout( triggerClick, 1000 );
 })()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample click should be trigerred only once because you don't have recursion.

Try following:

```
$(this).find('.slide').each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(3000 * index).click();
});
```

You will create all timeouts at the same time but with different period.

Comment: [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) will delay a queue, in this case the fx queue which looks to be empty. It doesn't delay the next action in the function chain.

Comment: I tried it like this a few different ways and found that when using .each it will ignore the timeout.